# Element is not being removed from DOM when remove() on parent element is called when holding an instance in another class

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery extended class (Class2) which is initialized by another jquery extended class (Class1).

Class1 adds a div container element to the DOM, and initializes Class2. Class2 takes an argument which is the div container element from Class1 and adds a child to that container.

As discussed in this thread [Eventmanager that calls other objects' functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152438/eventmanager-that-calls-other-objects-functions), an manager holds a pointer to an instance of Class2.

In Class1 I call remove() on the container element and want all child elements to also be removed completely. But when I create a new instance of Class2 and it adds a child element again, then I have two child elements. If I do this over and over again I get one child element (which is added one time by Class2) more each time.

This is caused by that I hold an instance of Class2 in the manager. So I'm looking for a solution to remove the instance from the manager when elements that Class2 knows about is being removed. I know how to do this manually, but I want to see if this can be done somewhat magically by using events or something like that.

The manager holds an instance in order to call functions in different instances.
The solution need to work cross-browser, and at least IE8.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We will have to see your code to know how to advise you more specificaly.  Otherwise, there's too much guessing involved for how you wrote it and what can/should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you are creating a div-container by class1, calling class2 which inserts child-elements into that div-container?

If you want to remove the container and all of its children, try this:

```
$('#container_id').empty().remove();
```

which deletes the container-content and removes it from the DOM-tree.

Comment: That would have worked, but since I hold an instance of Class2 the child element isn't removed.

Comment: Mhm.. what about writing an extra line of code in which you remove the class2-elements?